# Relationship between Linear functionals and subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

*I am using Linear Algebra second  edition,KENNETH HOFFMAN | RAY KUNZE   page 101*

Now let us discuss the relationship between linear functionals and subspaces. **If $f$ is a non-zero linear functional ,then rank of $f$ is $1$ because the range of $f$ is a non-zero subspace of the scalar field and must(therefore) be the scalar field**. If the underlying space $V$ is finite-dimensional , the rank plus nullity theorem tells us that null space $N_f$ has dimension

$$\operatorname{dim}N_f=\operatorname{dim} V-1$$

My question is why the rank of $f$ is $1$? Please explain the dark part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $f$ is a non zero linear functional, there exists $x_0 \in V$, such that $$f(x_0)=\alpha\implies \frac{1}{\alpha}f(x_0)=f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}x_0\right)=1.$$ for some $\alpha \neq 0$.

Then for any $\beta \in \mathbb{F}$, $$\beta=\beta .1=\beta f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}x_0\right)=f\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}x_0\right)$$

Hence every element of the $\mathbb{F}$ could be hit as a scalar multiple of $x_0$ and and $1 \in \mathbb{F}$ generates $\mathbb{F}$ , hence rank of $f$ is 1.